# Why Math.floor return nothing when we write it into HTML angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller = "myCntrl">  
    <pre>floor 1: {{Math.floor( value )  }}</pre>  
    <pre>floor 2: {{value }}</pre>  
    <pre>floor 3: {{value | number : 0 }}</pre>  
    <pre>floor 1 from controller: {{newValue }}</pre>  
</div>
```

*Controller*

```
app.controller('myCntrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.value = 1233.8435;
    $scope.newValue = Math.floor(1233.8435);    
});
```

The output:

```
floor 1: 
floor 2: 1233.8435
floor 3: 1,234
floor 1 from controller: 1233
```

Generally I'm looking for the proper way to get `1233`.

I don't want to invoke new method in controller.

Why `Math.floor` returns nothing?

Thanks,

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/795/)

Comment: What's `$scope.Math.floor`?

Comment: Math.floor refers to javascript

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740329/math-functions-in-angular-bindings

Comment: This should actually be included in the Angular docs: *"expressions are not JavaScript `eval`. Check out the following example..."*

Comment: Actually, it is: "It might be tempting to think of Angular view expressions as JavaScript expressions, but that is not entirely correct, since Angular does not use a JavaScript eval() to evaluate expressions." (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Comment: You are correct. I'm just saying that they should include this very example in it. :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Expressions are evaluated on the $scope. If you do this in your controller

`$scope.Math=Math;`

it would work.

Answer (score 20):

In this case, AngularJS `<span>{{value}}</span>` ([expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)) is shorthand for `<span ng-bind="value"></span>` and `ng-bind` acts on the current `scope`.

Your current scope is the one defined by `myCntrl` so `ng-bind="value"` is evaluated as `$scope.value`.

AngularJS has no way of making a distinction between the global `Math` namespace and `$scope.Math`, so it treats it like any other scoped expression.

I'd advise against using `$scope.Math=Math;`.

The correct way to do it is using a [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter):

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('floor', function(){

    return function(n){
        return Math.floor(n);
    };
});
```

Comment: +1 for that. Maybe you could skip the wrapper function and return `Math.floor;`

Comment: +1 for doing it the angular way.  This is a much better answer than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in your controller

```
<div ng-controller = "myCntrl">  
  <pre>floor 1: {{Mathvalue}}</pre>  
  <pre>floor 2: {{value }}</pre>  
  <pre>floor 3: {{value | number : 0 }}</pre>  
</div>
```

---

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', []);

app.controller('myCntrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.value = 1233.8435; 
  $scope.Mathvalue = Math.floor(1233.8435);
});

app.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular expression doesn't support all javascript method, for example Math.floor(), you can declear a floor function on your $scope and delegete Meth floor