# Rounding a sum on the fly using Angular databinding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue where I need to essentially do math on the fly and not a function. I have 3 elements that need to be multiplied and have yet to find a solution. I have added the element "number:2" but that only pertains to the elements being multiplied and not to the whole sum. Below I have my current code.

```
 <input disabled name='e_total{{$index}}' type='text' id='e_total{{$index}}' value='{{ (item.quantity | number:2)  * (item.cost | number:2) * (item.markup | number:2)}}'/>
```

Is there a way to do this with binding? I have also changed my input type to number but that does not seem to work. Thanks for any direction.

Comment: I think this will probably answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740329/math-functions-in-angular-bindings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter at the end like:
`{{ vm.item.quantity * vm.item.cost * vm.item.markup | number:2 }}`

full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tjruzpmb/197/

Comment: Thank you. Your idea seems to work, but for whatever reason it doesn't on my end. Not sure if I have some other issue going on. Doesn't throw an error either.