# Math functions in angular2 bindings

Tags: angular, typescript, math-functions

Is there a way to use math functions in angular2 bindings?

***example***

```
<div class="partition-panel">
                <b class="pull-left">{{Math.round(variable/12*2)}}</b>
                <b class="pull-right">{{Math.round(variable/12*2)}}</b>
 </div>
```

when try to use this i got error

```
Cannot read property 'round' of undefined
```

Also the similar question is answered for [angular1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740329/math-functions-in-angular-bindings)

Comment: The problem is, from the template you only have access to the local scope of your `Component`, so you either have to define a helper method or assign `window.Math` to a member variable like Adrien suggested.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can try this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{Math.round(number)}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  Math = Math;
  number = 2.5;
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyfnin)

Comment: This worked, but I had to move the declaration to the component whose template needed Math.

Comment: You should be also able to avoid init Math on the constructor and simply write:

Math: Math = Math;

Answer (score 13):

For rounding numbers in Angular templates, you can use the DecimalPipe: `{{ value | number }}`

See all the rounding options in https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

For all the built-in pipes, check
https://angular.io/api?type=pipe

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it makes use of pipes instead of using functions in template bindings. Also less code needed than declaring Math as a variable.

Comment: Careful though, as the rounding done by the pipe is different for negative numbers.

Comment: There are no real rounding options though. This [only rounds "to-nearest" per the docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#digitsinfo) and does not replace `floor()` or `ceil()`.