# Angular 4 - show one decimal

Tags: angular, pipe

How I can show only one decimal in the p tag. if I want to use pipe, how I can use it ?

```
<p> {{total.one / total.two *100}} </p>
```

Comment: This could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740329/math-functions-in-angularjs-bindings

Comment: Check angular [DecimalPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this code will help you

```
{{total.one | number : '1.2-2'}}

{{(total.one / total.two *100)|number : '1.2-2'}}

{{(total.one / total.two *100)|number : '1.1-1'}}
```

2-2 is value of decimal points

so 1-1 shows you one decimal point 
this code show you 2 decimal pointe